# Python Regex to find all percentages within the contents of html tags

Tags: python, regex

There are 2 conditions I'm trying to meet with a regex being used on scraped html.  All example code are strings:

1. ex_string = `<p>40% flights: Private bookings 20-15% bonus: Private airfairs 10% Excellence: Public Vacation 5-0% persons: Public Sightseeing</p>`

I'm using `re.findall(r'\d+%', ex_string)` which yields: 
['40%', '15%', '10%', '0%']

But in a situation with 20-15% I need to get '20-15%' within the output instead of just 15%.

2. `<table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td style="width: 50%;">85%</td>`

Using `re.findall(r'\d+%', ex_string)` here gets ['100%', '85%] however I only want percentages in which 'width: ' isn't preceding.

The desired result for the second example would be ['85%'].

What modification need to be made to satisfy both?

Comment: Use an HTML parser.

Comment: re.findall(r'\d+-\d+%|\d+%', ex_string) solved the first condition

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML parser will make this much simpler. If you want a regex solution, negative look behind could be a way.

```
import re

ex_string = """
<p>40% flights: Private bookings 20-15% bonus: Private airfairs 10% Excellence: Public Vacation 5-0% persons: Public Sightseeing</p>
<table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 50%;">85%</td>
"""

g = re.findall(r'(?<!width: )(?<!\d)(\d+%|\d+\-\d+%)', ex_string)
print(g)
```

which means `width:` and `\d` should not precede `(\d+%|\d+\-\d+%)`.

output:

```
['40%', '20-15%', '10%', '5-0%', '85%']
```